# Do new files added to an NTFS compressed directory use the same algorithm as existing files in the directory

Tags: ntfs, compression

I have used the command line tool "compact" to compress D:\SteamLibrary with the LZX algorithm, It has marked these directories as "compressed" in file attributes.  Will new files added to this directory automatically be compressed with LZX or will windows compress them with the standard algorithm?

Comment: Why did you do that? If you lost those files you could just re-download them from Steam, right? Compressing files makes using the slower, and you want your games to run quickly.

Comment: If a folder has the attribute, new files created inside it will also be compressed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/compression-attribute On NTFS it uses Lempel-Ziv compression. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-compression-and-decompression

Comment: See also https://github.com/chrisborecki/LZXAuto They will be automatically **de**compressed when used

Comment: @Gantendo; it seems to me this is an answer, so why put it in comments?

Comment: @JoepvanSteen Couple of reasons. 1 I don't believe in reputation/karma/that weird thing that people care so much about.  2 people have weird expectations of answers e.g. in the comments i can just drop a link but in an answer people expect me to spend 73 hours to copy all information from an external website including layout and images (making sure the link is in archive.org is not good enough) 3 ik ben een raar kind

Comment: @Gantendo, lol. Ja maar .. I'm not too interested in Karma either, but for people looking for answers it may help the answer is actually in the answers. Anyway, someone else will take Karma points for it ;)

Comment: I invite anyone to take my comments as inspiration for answers. Many people find it rather difficult to earn their first points. "Be equally indifferent to blame and praise." -- Some old dude, probably

Comment: @Gantendo : Nice idea to leave Karma points to others. But at least for me it's distracting seeing some lazy breadcrumbs thrown down in the comments. In most cases I abandon such polluted question without posting any answer. It's like you're biting once in a pie and then change to the next one. — I think a more polite technique to leave the karma points for others would be to do delayed answering so others have the chance and time to grab the job. Extending an incomplete or weak answer by qualified comments is also a nice possibility to improve quality without distraction.

Comment: @dodrg A downside is that I think that a lot of people who don't receive an answer or comment with 85% of an answer will get distracted and never return (but I do not have data to confirm or deny that). Probably an interesting question for the SE data explorer: "How long does it take for someone who asks a question to lose interest and not return". I doubt they have that kind of data, but if they do it can be used to optimize the order in which questions are presented.

Comment: @Gantendo : The possibility to loose the asking user might be a point. But what are we really loosing? Someone wo is not enough interested in the answer of his question to wait for it, shows how much worth it is. So when the one does not react on a feedback request, I won't answer it as obviously he is not valuating my time of life. But answering an interesting question "to late" is at least of value for the board. The only lost thing is a short-sighted lecher and his Karma points. — The most obvious are the ones asking to solve their scholar homework and hardly provide any "Karma feedback".

Comment: @Gantendo. I am compressing the files with NTFS compression in order to get more games on the disk.   You can see significant savings (100+ Gigabytes saved) in games like ARK and 5-10 GB In other games.  I don’t really care about data loss.  Performance impact is minimal here as i have more than enough CPU to decompress in real time)    My goal is to see if i need to the compact command every time i add new files to the directory and weather i need to use the /F flag to recompress files compressed with the default algorithm (as modern windows defaults to XPRESS4K).

Comment: My OS drive is quite small (only 1TB) so i am storing my steam library on my D drive. It’s not a backup of those games and i have fast internet so so loss of the files isn’t a concern.